# Should I use the "delete" for the object member which initialized by "new" operator in constructor?

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator

I have a question about `new` and `delete`:
Should I use `delete` for the input parameter or member object, e.g.：

https://github.com/jwbecalm/Head-First-Design-Patterns-in-CPP/blob/main/ch01_Strategy/main.cpp

Should I use `delete` on the object allocated by `new FlyNewWay()`?

```
// change behavior in runtime
mallardDuck->setFlyBehavior(new FlyNewWay());

// create custom MallarDuck on stack.
MallarDuck rocketDuck =  MallarDuck(new FlyWthRocket(), new NewQuack());
```

and in MallardDuck constructor:

https://github.com/jwbecalm/Head-First-Design-Patterns-in-CPP/blob/main/ch01_Strategy/MallarDuck.cpp

```
MallarDuck:: MallarDuck(){
    cout << "in MallarDuck:: MallarDuck()" << endl;
    // 为MallarDuck 赋值其特有的行为
    m_flyBehavior = new FlyWithWings();
    m_quackBehavior = new SimpleQuack();
}
```

SHould I use `delete` to free `m_flyBehavior` and `m_quackBehavior`? but these two are members of object.

I can easily add `delete` in destructor of `MallarDuck`.

```
MallarDuck::~MallarDuck(){
    cout << "in ~MallarDuck()" << endl;
     delete m_flyBehavior;   
     delete m_quackBehavior;
}
```

but how about the input parameter mentioned in the first code block? or is this way to design and pass value not recommended? do you have some suggestions?

the setFlyBehavior() is as follows, if I add delete fb, it will delete m_flyBehavior also for my understanding because both fb and m_flyBehavior point to the same memory address.

```
void Duck::setFlyBehavior(FlyBehavior* fb){
    m_flyBehavior = fb;
    cout << "in Duck::setFlyBehavior()" <<endl;
}
```

after the setFlyBehavior(), both fb and m_flyBehavior point to the same memory address. so in the deconstructor: ~MallarDuck(), if I delete m_flyBehavior, the input parameter fb where it point to will be free too.
So, the delete in deconstructor ~MallarDuck() is enough. thx .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes whenever you use `new` keyword to allocate some memory then you must always use `delete` to free up that memory later when no longer needed. Otherwise you will have a memory leak as in your program. In your case you should use `delete` inside the destructor in the MallarDuck.cpp .

Other solution would be to use smart pointers like `unique_ptr` so that you don't have to explicitly free the memory.

unique_ptr`'s syntax would something like:

```
unique_ptr<FlyWithWings> m_flyBehavior(new FlyWithWings());
```

In case you are confused about whether there is a memory leak or not, you can just add a `cout` statement in the destructor of `FlyWithWings` and `SimpleQuack` to confirm whether the destructor is called on these objects or not. Then accordingly you can use smart pointers if needed.

**Steps to confirm if you have memory leak**

1. Add some `std::cout<<"destructor ran;` statement inside the destructors of `FlyWithWings` and `SimpleQuack`.
2. Also, in this case don't use `delete` explicitly on the data members inside the destructor of `MallarDuck`.
3. Then if you see that the destructor is not ran on the data members `m_flyBehavior` and `m_quackBehavior` this will mean you have a memory leak and you need to use `delete` explicitly on the appropriate data members in the destructor of `MallarDuck`.

Answer to your **Edit**

> how about the input parameter mentioned in the first code block?

For the statement `mallardDuck->setFlyBehavior(new FlyNewWay());` you can use the following code:

```
void Duck::setFlyBehavior(FlyBehavior* fb){
    //delete the old memory but note again we should check whether the pointer is valid or not
   //check for a valid pointer
    if (m_flybehavior)
    {
       
        delete m_flybehavior;//free the old memory
    }
    
    m_flyBehavior = fb;//so m_flybehavior points to some new memory

    //no need to use delete now on m_flybehavior because  in the destructor ~MallarDuck() you have delete m_flybehavior
    cout << "in Duck::setFlyBehavior()" <<endl;
}
```

And for the statement

```
MallarDuck rocketDuck =  MallarDuck(new FlyWthRocket(), new NewQuack());
```

as the `MallarDuck`'s destructor have `delete` for the data members, it will free up that memory. Also this assumes the input parameters are assigned to the data members.

Comment: I just now find a source code also using c++: https://sourceforge.net/projects/hfdp-cpp/,  it doesn't use the delete to free memory, so I'm confused..

Comment: @irwin In case you are confused about whether there is a memory leak or not , you can just add a `cout` statement in the destructor of `FlyWithWings` and `SimpleQuack` to confirm whether the destructor is called on these objects or not. Then accordingly you can use smart pointers if needed.

Comment: @irwin To confirm that whether you have a memory leak or not, these are the steps. Add some `std::cout<<"destructor ran;` statement inside `FlyWithWings` and `SimpleQuack`. Also, in this case don't use `delete` explicitly in the destructor of `MallarDuck`. Then if you see that the destructor is not ran on the data members `m_flyBehavior` and `m_quackBehavior` this will mean you have a memory leak.

Comment: @irwin I have edited my answer to answer your edited question. Check out the edit part of my answer.

Comment: in the setFlyBehavior(),  if delete p, then m_flyBehavior is also deleted for my understanding. I paste the set method in my quesion.

Comment: @irwin Where is the set method? I can't see it in your question. Have you posted it.  Also in the last comment you said "then m_flyBehavior is also deleted for my understanding". But i didn't understand what you meant by this. Can you clarify it a bit here.

Comment: I just paste the setFlyBehavior(), sorry. please refresh the web browser. Now I seem to understand. after the setFlyBehavior(), both fb and m_flyBehavior point to the same memory address. so in the deconstructor: ~MallarDuck(), if I delete m_flyBehavior, the input parameter fb where it point to will be free too. am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238346/discussion-between-irwin-and-anoop-rana).

Comment: @irwin ok now i see the body of your `setFlyBehavior`. As you said `fb` and `m_flyBehavior` point to the same memory.  So the destructor: `~MallarDuck()` will take care of deleting that memory, so you don't have to use `delete` inside the `setflyBheavior()` because otherwise the same memory will be delete twice which is not what we want. But note that when you write `m_flyBehavior= fb` inside `setflyBehavior()` then if `m_flybehavior` is already pointing to some old memory you must free it ,that is use `delete m_flybehavior` to free that old memory.

Comment: @irwin I have edited my answer according to your given `setflyBehavior()`. You can check it out. Also, if you don't want to do this memory management explicitly you can use smart pointers.

Answer (score 1):

All pointers created with `new` must be deleted at some point. In C++ you wouldn't usually give a pointer to function like `setFlyBehavior()`, because it is not obvious who should delete the pointer. However it seems you are using polymorphism, so you need to use some kind of pointer.

If the function is called like `setFlyBehavior(new FlyNewWay())`, the class should delete the pointer. But the user might also call it with an existing pointer and delete it later. The pointer would be deleted multiple times.

```
// Incorrect usage
FlyBehavior* way = new FlyNewWay();
duck1->setFlyBehavior(way);
duck2->setFlyBehavior(way);
delete way;
```

Your class has no way knowing how the user created the pointer. You shouldn't trust that the class is being used correctly. Instead, take `std::unique_ptr<FlyBehavior>` as parameter and save that in your class.

Create the arguments with `std::make_unique`:

```
mallardDuck->setFlyBehavior(std::make_unique<FlyNewWay>());
```

Comment: thx, vll, I will try to find some tutorials for the std::unique_ptr.  about this question, it' clear, and I edit the post for my understanding.  my c++ has a long way to go....